Using a measure in a filter
I created a measure and I world like to use in a filter.
The measure select one part of text (call the measure code) from another column.
How can I do it?
How can use Code as a filter?
Code = right(table[dim])




dim
right(filter)




ciao1
1


hola3
3


dhsr
r



I need 1/ 3 / r in a filter.
I tried to add in a column but power Bi tell me that I have a scalar error in The table (I think the problem is column dim)

I don't think measure can be added to the filter visual. Could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

I add information

sry, can't understand the info that you added.

I suggest you to create a calculated column and add it into page level filter.
Code
Count of TeamID = COUNTAX(FILTER('Table','Table'[TeamID]=EARLIER('Table'[TeamID])),'Table'[TeamID])

I don’t undestand, where I can use the measure I have already calculed?
